# Using Bayesian Optimization with discrete grid points

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the [BayesianOptimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) package to optimize Hyperparameters of a [sklearn Decision tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html). There are continuous parameters like

**min_weight_fraction_leaf in the intervall (0.1,0.4)**

but also discrete parameters like

**criterion =  "mse","friedman_mse",...**

or combinations of None and ints like

**max_depth = None, 1,2,...**

```
def DT_optimizer_function(criterion,max_depth,min_weight_fraction_leaf):
    """
    Function with unknown internals we wish to maximize.
    """
    return -x ** 2 - (y - 1) ** 2 + 1

from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

# Bounded region of parameter space
pbounds = {'criterion': ?,
           'max_depth': ?,
           'min_weight_fraction_leaf' = (0.1,0.4)
          }

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
    f=DT_optimizer_function,
    pbounds=pbounds,
    random_state=1,
)

optimizer.maximize(
    init_points=2,
    n_iter=3,
)

print(optimizer.max)
```

Is it possible to optimize the discrete values too?

Answer (score 1):

According to their [docs](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/master/examples/advanced-tour.ipynb)

> There is no principled way of dealing with discrete parameters using
> this package.

However, you may cast the floating point sample from bayes opt to `int` or process it in a way that serves your purpose. For example, in your snippet above you may do the following:

```
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

def function_to_be_optimized(criterion,max_depth):
   # map bayes_opt sample to a categorical value
   # values below 0.5 mapped to 'mse', above 0.5 mapped to 'friedman_mse' 
   criterion_list = ['mse', 'friedman_mse'] 
   criterion = criterion_list[round(criterion)] 
   
   # map bayes_opt sample to an integer value
   max_depth = int(max_depth)
   max_depth = max_depth if max_depth!=0 else None

   magical_number = ...
   return magical_number
   

pbounds = {
           'criterion': (0,1),
           'max_depth': (0,5)
          }

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
    f=function_to_be_optimized,
    pbounds=pbounds,
    random_state=42,
)

optimizer.maximize(
    init_points=2,
    n_iter=3,
)
```

I understand that this is not an ideal solution since the categorical values may not enjoy the smoothness properties that the a real valued parameter does.